# SQL Server php datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a database which will hold some `datetime` values.

So I defined the column to be `datetime` type, and I have this calendar.

So, which should be the format of the calendar input in order for the date time to work?

Because I need to make some searches i.e

```
Select FROM table_name between date1 to date2
```

For the moment it is:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

I'm using this:

```
$today = date("dd/mm/yyyy");                  
$strSQL = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE data_e_shitjes=$today";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependant** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, so when i insert a date it goes in the database like this:
18/12/2012 00:00:00

So, how should i have the format of today's date to compare it with?

Comment: @OziOz: the `DATETIME` type in SQL Server is a binary numerical format - it has no string formatting associated with it. You can output it in any string format you like

Comment: sO COULD YOU PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS?

Comment: Yes, but it goes on the database like this: 18/12/2012 00:00:00
How can i compare to today;'s date? i mean i need to retrieve all info that match with today date

Comment: it won't work like this:
WHERE forma.data_e_shitjes='18/12/2012 00:00:00'

Comment: @OziOz: what **version** of SQL Server are you using? If you're on **2008** or newer - you could use `DATE` datatype (instead of `DATETIME`) if you only need the date (and no TIME portion)

Comment: @OziOz: then you need to do `WHERE yourDate >= '20121218' AND yourDate < '20121219'` to get all rows for today's date

Comment: yes that's ok, but how can i convert my datetime to 20121218 in the query?